# Updating Nested Data in Flutter Firebase's Firestore database

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need some help updating the following nested data in flutter:

```
{
  story: [
    0: {
      'views': {
        // Updated DATA here
      }
    },
    1: {
      'views': {
        // Or here
      }
    }
    // Some other data
  ]
}
```

How can I updated data in firebase using above structure in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a SetOptions parameter when you set a new value

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('...').document(id).set(newObject, SetOptions(merge:true);
```

Answer (score 0):

With this structure I believe the only option you have is to read the data first,
update it locally and then save it again into Firestore with either `setData` or `updateData`.